# New to json/ajax .. The Console error is Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json

I am having a problem with my code. Please note that I am completely new on this so please forgive me if the solution is easy. I DID try to find a solution before posting this and I have found lots of post with a similar console error, however none that relate to my problem (or i just don't understand it well enough).

I have posted a JSFiddle version of what I am doing that works, and then another one that I have in a GitHub that is throwing an error.. aside of where it points to external documents, the function is the same. However on my Github full version, I am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". Reading other peoples problems, it would seem like the object is not getting converted correctly, but if that is the case, I don't know why it works in JSFiddle.

Here is the Snippet of the js code.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $( "#sortable1, #sortable2, #sortable3" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();


    //Some code
    $("#sortable3").sortable();
    //Some more code
    $("#addStuff").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var itemSelector = $("#myList li"),
            items = [],
            dataObj = {};
        $.each(itemSelector, function(i, v) {
            items.push($(v).val());
        });
        //I Am Sure There Is A Better Way Of Sending Checked Items Than A Ton Of IF Statements, However This Works..
        if(document.getElementById('bacon').checked) {
            items.push($("#bacon").val());
        }        
        if(document.getElementById('bananapeppers').checked) {
            items.push($("#bananapeppers").val());
        }          
        if(document.getElementById('blackolives').checked) {
            items.push($("#blackolives").val());
        }        
        if(document.getElementById('greenpeppers').checked) {
            items.push($("#greenpeppers").val());
        }         

        dataObj.stuff = items;
        $.ajax({
            url: '/echo/json/',
            data: {
                json: JSON.stringify(dataObj)
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $("#sortable3").empty();
                $.each(data.stuff, function(k, v) {


     $("#sortable3").append("<li>" + v + "</li>");
            })
        },
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        cache: false
    });
});
```

Here is the Link to the JSFiddle version that works:
http://jsfiddle.net/1ukyLgnh/5/

Here is a Github Repository of the full thing that is not working correctly:
https://github.com/dhierholzer/Basiconlineorderingone

If it matters, I am testing it through a WAMP server and debugging through a program called Light Table

One Last note, On my Github version I added a line 
window.alert(dataObj.stuff); just to make sure that the values were being passed through at least that far, and they are.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where in your code do you try to access length?

Comment: the only places I try to access length are functions where I am checking how many radio buttons are checked. Ex "var cnt = $("input[name='toppingtypes']:checked").length;" but as you can see, I am defining a var there and also, the console is not throwing an error until it gets to the sortable page (the last fade in window which is the function I have showing in the JSfiddle link)

Comment: You cannot use the `$` operator for jQuery in wordpress as it uses noconflict. Replace `$` with the word `jQuery`, this is the simplest method i find (there are others). The error you have described should be attached to a line of code, but if it works in jsfiddle and assuming you have the exact same html in wp, its more than likely the naming issue, if its not, you need to find where the code fails, more than likely it is as you suggest, the attempt to access the object has failed, meaning the html element does not exist.

Comment: Thank you, however, I am not using wordpress.. I have no underlying CMS of any sort. I am just running on localhost via a WAMP server. none the less, I will start messing with using different operators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.each` uses `length` property, your problem is most likely with the data that is returned from your `AJAX` call on which you call `each`. You can reproduce your problem easily in your jsfiddle by changing the name of data.stuff, you'll get the error:
http://jsfiddle.net/7d2wqkpq/

And you have an error in your debugging alert. You're checking if `dataObj` is ok, but `dataObj` is the object you sent in your ajax call, not what is returned. Replace `alert(dataObj.stuff)` with `alert(data.stuff)` and you'll probably get undefined. From then it should be easy to fix your code.

Comment: That totally worked! Thanks so much Julien! After I got passed that part, I then learned that my jquery 2.0 did not support my sortable options for some reason? anyways, I instead loaded 1.6.4 (same version that is on the working Jsfiddle) and then it worked!